CH32V003 Auto-wakeup Window Comparison Value Register problem
I've stumbled upon something I can't understand.
The MCU is CH32V003, RISC-V, RV32E model. The compiler is gcc version 8.2.0 (xPack GNU RISC-V Embedded GCC, 64-bit), supplied by manufacturer. The optimization flag is -O0.
This variant works well. "Well" means that the MCU goes to the standby mode and wakes up after ~2 seconds.
void EnterStandby(const u32 seconds)
{
 /* the code before */
 PWR->AWUWR = (199*seconds)/100; // it is Auto-wakeup Window Comparison Value Register (PWR_AWUWR)
                  // 6-bit wide (0x3F max), the other bits are reserved.
 /* the code after */
}

assembly
0000027e:   lw      a4,-20(s0)
00000282:   mv      a5,a4
00000284:   slli    a5,a5,0x1
00000286:   add     a5,a5,a4
00000288:   slli    a5,a5,0x3
0000028a:   add     a5,a5,a4
0000028c:   slli    a5,a5,0x3
0000028e:   sub     a5,a5,a4
00000290:   lui     s1,0x40007
00000294:   li      a1,100
00000298:   mv      a0,a5
0000029a:   jal     0xc0 <__udivsi3>
0000029c:   mv      a5,a0
0000029e:   sw      a5,12(s1)

This variant does not work, however, the PWR->AWUWR value is the same. "Does not work" means that  the MCU goes to the standby mode and wait forever.
void EnterStandby(const u32 seconds)
{
 /* the code before */
  PWR->AWUWR = (201*seconds)/100;
 /* the code after */
}

assembly
0000027e:   lw      a4,-20(s0)
00000282:   mv      a5,a4
00000284:   slli    a5,a5,0x1
00000286:   add     a5,a5,a4
00000288:   slli    a5,a5,0x3
0000028a:   add     a5,a5,a4
0000028c:   slli    a5,a5,0x3
0000028e:   add     a5,a5,a4
00000290:   lui     s1,0x40007
00000294:   li      a1,100
00000298:   mv      a0,a5
0000029a:   jal     0xc0 <__udivsi3>
0000029c:   mv      a5,a0
0000029e:   sw      a5,12(s1)

So the only difference is  0000028e:   add/sub     a5,a5,a4.
caller
int main(void)
{
    u8 StandBySeconds = 2u;
    EnterStandby(StandBySeconds);
}

Note that if StandBySeconds=1u it does work regardless of the multiplier (199 or 201). It looks like there is an overflow somewhere.
What is the reason of this behavior?
EDIT
The page with the CH32V003 reference manual. The register is in page 9 (keyword PWR_AWUWR).

I would highly recommend looking at optimized code. -O0 will often give you a headache with terrible redundant assembly.

Effectively you are writing 3 and 4, respectively, into AWUWR. Does that ring a bell? -- Would you mind to add a link to the data sheet / programmer's manual?

@ThomasJager I always thought that -O0 is the best for debug, but I see that it is useful to try to optimize. Thnx.

@thebusybee no, it does not, because it also works for 200. Added the link.

It was surprisingly hard to write stable reproducible example. Ultimately, it is the clock issues. To reduce power consumption, the system clock divider was set to 128 -> sysclk = 187.5 kHz. The autowakeup clock (LSI) has fixed frequency of 128 kHz. The reference manual says

Note: After the LSION bit is cleared to 0, the bit requires 3
LSI cycles to clear 0.

But nothing about what happens when LSION is set to 1. I suppose, if the core clock is too low, a racing condition occurs. Not sure, why the outcome differs so much for near identical assemblies. To fix the trouble, one can either increase the sysclock frequency, or add some nops.
void EnterStandby(const u32 seconds)
{
    RCC->RSTSCKR |= RCC_LSION; // enable LSI clock
    PWR->AWUWR = (201*seconds)/100;
    //asm("nop"); asm("nop"); // uncomment for stable operation
    while (0 == (RCC->RSTSCKR & RCC_LSIRDY)); // wait for LSI clock
    __WFE(); // sleep
    RCC->RSTSCKR &= (u32)~(RCC_LSION); // disable LSI clock 
}

